# Finding Types that implement specific Methods using CQL

Tags: ndepend, cql, cqlinq

I'm refining the built in dead code query in NDEpend and I'm finding a lot of false positives from standalone programs (i.e. w/ Main() entrypoints).

I noticed that the built in unused types query has this clause:

```
 !NameIs "Program" AND // Generally, types named Program 
                       // contain a Main() entry-point 
                       // method and this condition avoid 
                       // to consider such type as 
                       // unused code.
```

Is it impossible to write something like

```
HasMethodNamed "Main"
```

instead? That's what I'd really like to select for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can complete your CQL rule with a `HasMethodNamed "Main"`.

For that:

1. [Convert your CQL rule to a CQLinq rule](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CQLinq_CQL.aspx)
2. add the [CQLinq](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL) *where* clause  `&& t.Methods.Where(m => m.SimpleName == "Main").Any()`